# mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, database

I have mysql database which was working fine earlier. After getting too many connections error. I have increased max connection and restarted my centos server. But after restart I used below command to connect to server.
 `mysql -uroot -p`

But I am getting below errors.
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2).`

I tried all the options available on google. But it didn't worked for me. Some are saying to reinstall mysql, but I have data in GB's which I don't want to lost. Please can anyone help me to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure all of your previous connections have been `kill` ed with restart of the server? Are you sure that restart of the server provoked an explicit restart of the DB? The problem might be that the server doesn't launch SQL automatically & your DB is simply off.

Comment: I have tried to restart the server also after reboot by using command.
sudo service mysqld restart. But I am getting error 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  mysqld.service
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are indexing the right socket file.

Try this and provide the output.

`check the socket in the my.cnf`

`cat /etc/my.cnf | grep -i socket`